# Login to a SSO site and extract data from a web page using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, single-sign-on

I'm trying to connect to an intranet web site (SSO) and read information from a specific web page. I attempted to achieve this using the following approaches:

1

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://internal.JMedia-ts/8978497.com"), HttpWebRequest)
'set the cookie container object
request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim data As String = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "USER10001", "******")
Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

Dim reader as StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim rawData As String
rawData = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

2 Used "Negociate", "Basic", "NTLM" as methods

```
Dim myRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://internal.JMedia-ts/8978497.com")
myRequest .Timeout = 90000 
Dim myCache As New CredentialCache()
myCache .Add(New Uri("https://internal.JMedia-ts/8978497.com"), "Negotiate", New NetworkCredential("USER10001", "*******"))
myRequest.Credentials = mycache
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Dim reader as StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim rawData As String
rawData= reader.ReadToEnd()
```

I don't get any errors but login fails in both cases. rawData variable shows I am redirected to generic web page saying... "*If you're a first time user click this link to acquire your password... etc...etc...*"
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Go through the process once in a normal browser, and use the browser's developer tools to record every HTTP request/response. Then filter out the css and images. You'll be left with html and javascript, and most of the javascript (maybe even ALL) won't apply to what you're doing. Then you'll especially need to review the exact HTTP requests your browser sent, whether GET or POST, along with the data included with those requests, and what responses each of those requests received, especially cookies and any tokens. Once you understand this, you'll need to duplicate those steps in your code.

Comment: Very good suggestion, please create an answer and I shall set is as solution.